# I am trying to code PHP into a progress bar that uses values from my DB

Tags: php, html, sql, database, progress-bar

I am very new to PHP, so be easy I know it is all bad. I am trying to use values from my DB to populate my progress bar. My connection to DB and everything works but I am not sure how to actually do it. I have tried two separate ways and neither seems to work, please assist me. I know the code is bad but it is just an assignment for class and the quickest and easiest way to get it working is all I need.

Version 1:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('inc/session.php');
include ('inc/connect.php');

$query = "select * from user where username='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$que3 = "select * from retirement where userID='$userID' ORDER BY year 
         DESC, month DESC LIMIT 1";
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $que3);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
$percent = $row2['balance'] / $row['nestEgg'];
$percent1 = $percent * 100;
echo '<div class="progress">'echo '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" 
        role="progressbar"aria-valuenow="$row['balance']; " aria-valuemin="0" 
        aria-valuemax="$row['nestEgg']; " style="width:echo '$percent1';"> ';
echo "Keep Saving";
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Version 2:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
        aria-valuenow="
            <?php
                $que3 = "select * from retirement where userID='$userID' ORDER BY year 
                  DESC, month DESC LIMIT 1";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $que3);
                $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
                $row['balance'];
            ?>
        " aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="
            <?php
                $query = "select * from user where username='$username'";
                $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $row['nestEgg'];
            ?>
        " style="width:
            <?php
                session_start();
                include ('inc/session.php');
                include ('inc/connect.php');

                $query = "select * from user where username='$username'";
                $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $que3 = "select * from retirement where userID='$userID' ORDER BY year 
                 DESC, month DESC LIMIT 1";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $que3);
                $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
                $percent = $row2['balance'] / $row['nestEgg'];
                $percent1 = $percent * 100;
                echo $percent1;
            ?>
        ">
        Keep Saving
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Syntax errors: `"width:echo '$percent1';"` fix that first. And format the code better. And show error messages. And you should learn seperate php code from html code. like: `$a=1234;   ?><div><?=$a;?>`. Means move all you sql above the html part and bind needed values to variables.

Comment: You're not actually trying to create a *real* progress bar are you..? It's not something that's being dynamically updated while something happens - just a bar on the screen that shows someone's balance in relation to the amount required for their retirement *"nest egg"* ..? No complex poling or Ajax required is what I'm getting at I guess...

Comment: @CD001Correct it is not actually a progress bar for like uploading it is more of a tracker.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard for me to say what the exact issue is without seeing the results of your code. If you make a JSFiddle that would be really helpful. One thing that immediately jumped is in example one the code where you echo out the progress bar is not correct. You need to use '.' to concatenate your variables to your text. See below for correct set up:

```
echo '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="' . $row['balance'] . '" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="' . $row['nestEgg'] . '" style="width:' . $percent1 . '" />';
```